# Azure Web App using Node 10.x instead of 14.x

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure Web Apps and every time I try to make it use node 14.x it resets back to 10.x after every deployment.

When I go to Configuration > General the Stack is blank, I have to select Node and then 14.x to make it work.

Edit: Linux is used not Windows

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem by adding

```
runtimeStack: "NODE|14-lts"
```

in the yaml file, 16.x is not yet supported so it defaults back to 10.x

Answer (score 1):

Add `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` app setting for the Node version, but make sure the exact version you fill in is installed on the workers (assuming Windows workers here, since you don't specify) -

```
https://{yourWebAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime
```

That's the Kudu API route returning runtime versions. Pick the latest installed Node version from there.

Your app setting becomes

```
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 14.16.0
```

As long as you don't remove or overwrite this app setting, your Node version will stay consistent across code deployments.

Tracking a GitHub issue here since the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-windows) is confusing about the version values -
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/79475

Comment: I tried that but it still defaults to 10.x, sorry for not mentioning that in the original post but I use linux.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the deployment logs? Seems to work fine for me, remote says  `Using Node version: v14.17.4` and i can confirm the version by echoing `process.version` in [my web app](https://amisecurelinux.azurewebsites.net/). Maybe your `package.json` is specifying it's own Node version and that takes precedence over the web app runtime stack setting?

Comment: The problem was related to the runtimeStack I'm choosing, it wasn't supported by Azure Web Apps, I later realized I have to use 14-lts and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that even though in Azure Portal I specified the runtime stack...
[image]

...that I had to go into `Configuration` and choose the version I wanted again.  It defaulted back to `10`.

[image]